# Downloading file using Spring Portlet MVC

Tags: java, spring, portlet, spring-portlet-mvc

I want to allow the user to save file using mvc portlet.  In my code i am making an **ajax call** hence it has to be a resource response.

```
response.setContentType( "application/octet-stream" );
response.setProperty("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=\""+fname+"\"");
response.setContentLength(b.length);
OutputStream  po= response.getPortletOutputStream();
po.write(b,0,b.length);
po.flush();
po.close();
```

In ajax response when i do `alert(resp)`, I am getting the whole content of my file in alert but still not getting any option for download.

Please help and thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you get the response, you need to allow the user to download it. You can for example use the HTML `data:` *protocol* and redirect the browser to smt. like

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAA...
```

for a PNG image.

Anyway, can't you use a normal request to a portlet? It's trivial then.

Comment: I got it ..i made http request instead of ajax call.thanx for the support :)